# Updating a variable from a parent class in a child class is not being read correctly when calling an event in the parent class

Tags: inheritance, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have this interface event set up in an object. The event requires the use of a variable, which is set to be different for each child class of that object. However, when I call the interface event, the variable is read as the value that is set in the parent. In this case, render element is the variable which is set to 0 in the parent and is changed in the children via the class defaults. What am I doing wrong here?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new variable in the child blueprint that hides and is distinct from the parent variable.

Delete the variable in the child BP and show the parent variable:
[image: Show the inherited variables check box]

Compile the blueprint, and then change the default value.